# How to install the "David" bold and regular fonts on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

How can I install the "David" bold and regular fonts on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the font files to the `~/.fonts/` directory, (or `/usr/share/fonts` for system-wide installation).

Comment: Where can I download david family fonts? dont ubuntu have some package?

Comment: @Yosef: I only found one ["David" font family](http://www.linotype.com/472415/david-family.html), which is sold by Linotype (and therefore Ubuntu cannot provide it as a free package).

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/David+Libre

Answer (score 3):

I can't help with finding the fonts, but i do believe grawity has missed a step. According to my own notes, from the last time i had trouble installing fonts on ubuntu  the two steps i used were

> copy the fonts over to
>   /usr/share/fonts/TTF
>
> sudo 'fc-cache'

Comment: In my case, the font cache seemed to be rebuilt automatically in a few seconds. Not sure by which component.